# OpenCV Python support HaarDetectObjects documentation wrong?

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

The documentation for the OpenCV Python wrapper states that HaarDetectObjects have this prototype:

```
HaarDetectObjects(image, cascade, storage, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=3, flags=0, minSize=(0, 0))
```

But when I try to specify the minSize param I get this error:

```
cv.HaarDetectObjects( image, faceCascade, faceStorage, scale_factor=1.1, min_neighbors=3, flags=cv.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, min_size=(40,40) )
TypeError: function takes at most 6 arguments (7 given)
```

Is this the documentation wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Works for me with OpenCV 2.2.0 on Windows. Tested with facedetect.py example.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to specify that I'm using OpenCV 2.2.0 on Ubuntu

Comment: facedetect.py example uses the old version of the wrapper (from opencv.cv import *)...but I'm using the new ones (import cv). Also the example uses 7 arguments...

Comment: facedetect.py that comes with OpenCV 2.2.0 uses the new wrapper. Something must be wrong with your installation.

Comment: To make it work I had to revert to the old version.